# How should i move to the top this green container and center my 'sign up' text in it?

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

[The login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sKyh.png) There is this login page im trying to make but it isn't going like i want to , i want that little container at the top to stay at the very top instead it leaves some space for some reasons.

I tried padding 0 , also margin to force move it up but nothing seems to work.

```
.sign-up {
  border: 14px solid #00f535;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #b6f1c3;
  box-shadow: 10px 13px 20px 5px greenyellow;
}

#username {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#password {
  padding: 10px;;
}

#name {
  border: 0px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0x;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(117, 243, 117);
  font-family: open, sans, extrabold;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}



label {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 00px;
  margin: 0px;
}

input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
> box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
```

Comment: I would checkout [mcve] that will assist you in asking questions that will get you the best answers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.